# Segmentation fault (core dumped) al modificar valores en un vector de enteros

Tags: c, linux, algoritmos

El programa ejecuta diferentes algoritmos de ordenación sobre arrays, el problema ocurre al modificar los valores dentro de un array.

Durante la ejecución primero se lanza un test para comprobar que el algoritmo ordena bien y aquí funciona, a continuación se genera una serie de vectores de diferente tamaño con valores crecientes, decrecientes y pseudoaleatorios, cuando se ejecuta la ordenación sobre estos el código falla, en ambos casos se reservo memoria dinámica para los vectores.

En dos situaciones semejantes ocurren cosas distintas, estoy un poco perdido con el porqué de que esto ocurra.

```
==13523== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13523== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13523== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13523== Command: ../build/fusion
==13523==
==13523== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
-2, 10, 6, -9, 7, -6, -3, 6, -5, -1,
-9, -6, -5, -3, -2, -1, 6, 6, 7, 10,
 - Leyendo tiempos
 ************************************
ALGORITMO > fusion
        SITUATION > ascendente
==13523== Invalid read of size 4
==13523==    at 0x109FC6: fusion (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A098: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A083: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A083: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A0C1: ord_fusion (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x108C28: leerTiempo_v (c_computacional.c:43)
==13523==  Address 0x36 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13523==
==13523==
==13523== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==13523==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x36
==13523==    at 0x109FC6: fusion (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A098: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A083: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A083: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A06C: fusion_rec (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x10A0C1: ord_fusion (in /mnt/c/users/manuc/Desktop/Q1/Algoritmos/empiricaLT/build/fusion)
==13523==    by 0x108C28: leerTiempo_v (c_computacional.c:43)
==13523==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==13523==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==13523==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==13523==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==13523==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==13523==
==13523== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13523==     in use at exit: 2,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==13523==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 6,136 bytes allocated
==13523==
==13523== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13523==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13523==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13523==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13523==    still reachable: 2,000 bytes in 1 blocks
==13523==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13523== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13523==
==13523== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13523== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Includes

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Estas son las estructuras y los tipos definidos

```
typedef void (*typeSituationFunction)(int *v, int nargs);
typedef void (*typeAlgorithemFunction)(int *v, int nargs);

#define NUM_SITUACIONES 3
#define NUM_ALGORITMOS 1

typedef struct {
    char name[256];
    int isComplex;
    int index;
} funcion;

#define LOG (funcion) {"log(n)",0,0}
#define N_x (funcion) {"n",0,1}
#define NxLogN (funcion) {"n*log(n)",0,2}
#define Nexp_x (funcion) {"n^$",1,3}
#define Nexp_x_LOG (funcion) {"n^$*log(n)",1,4}

typedef  struct {
    funcion cota;
    double exp;
}cota_t;

typedef struct {
    int is_under_500;
    int is_anomalo;
    double tiempo;
} tempos;

typedef struct {
    cota_t sobre;
    cota_t ajus;
    cota_t sub;
    typeSituationFunction func;
    tempos tiempos[256];
    int valN[256];
    char sit_name[256];

} situacion;

typedef struct {
    int ini;
    int fin;
    int mult;
    int nTemp;
    typeAlgorithemFunction func;
    char alg_name[256];
    situacion sList[NUM_SITUACIONES];

} algoritmo;
```

Esta es una de las herramientas

```
void inicializar_semilla() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

void aleatorio(int *v, int n) {/* se generan números pseudoaleatorio_t entre -n y +n */
    int i, m=2*n+1;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
        v[i] = (rand() % m) - n;
}
void ascendente(int *v, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
        v[i] = i;
}
void descendente(int *v, int n){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = n - i - 1;
    }
}
```

Esta es la otra

```
double microsegundos(){
    struct timeval t;
    if (gettimeofday(&t, NULL) < 0)
        return 0.0;
    return (t.tv_usec + t.tv_sec * 1000000.0);
}
void leerTiempo_v(algoritmo alg, situacion sit, tempos tiempos[], int *tamV){
    double ta, tb, t, ti;
    int k, n, i;
    int *v;

    typeSituationFunction ini = sit.func;
    typeAlgorithemFunction ord = alg.func;

    int inicio = alg.ini;
    int fin = alg.fin;
    int mult = alg.mult;

    i = 0;
    printf("ALGORITMO > %s\n",alg.alg_name);
    printf("\tSITUATION > %s\n",sit.sit_name);

    for (n = inicio; n <= fin; n = n * mult) {
        tamV[i]=n;
        v = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        ini(v, n);
        ta = microsegundos();
        ord(v, n);
        tb = microsegundos();
        t = tb - ta;

        if (t < 500) {
            ta = microsegundos();
            for (k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
                ini(v, n);
                ord(v, n);
            }
            tb = microsegundos();
            t = tb - ta;

            ta = microsegundos();
            for (k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
                ini(v, n);
            }
            tb = microsegundos();

            ti = tb - ta;
            t = (t - ti) / k;

            tiempos[i] = (tempos){1,0,t};
            printf("\t\t > tiempo %f \n", tiempos[i].tiempo);
        } else {
            tiempos[i] = (tempos){0,0,t};
            printf("\t\t > tiempo %f \n", tiempos[i].tiempo);
        }
        i++;
        free(v);
    }
}
cota_t genCota(funcion func, double exp){
    cota_t cota;
    char *token1;
    char *token2;
    char aux[256];

    if(func.isComplex){
        cota.cota = func;
        cota.exp = exp;
        token1 = strtok(cota.cota.name,"$");
        token2 = strtok(NULL,"$");
        if(token2 != NULL) {
            sprintf(aux, "%s%2.1f%s", token1, cota.exp, token2);
            strcpy(cota.cota.name, aux);
        } else {
            sprintf(aux, "%s%2.1f", token1, cota.exp);
            strcpy(cota.cota.name, aux);
        }

    } else {
        cota.cota = func;
        cota.exp = 0;
    }

    return cota;
}

double execute(funcion op , int n, double exp, int derivada){

    if (!derivada) {

        switch (op.index) {
            case 0:
                return log(n);
            case 1:
                return n;
            case 2:
                return n*log(n);
            case 3:
                return pow(n,exp);
            case 4:
                return pow(n,exp)*log(n);
            default:
                return -1;
        }

    } else {

        switch (op.index) {
            case 0:
                return 1.0/n;
            case 1:
                return 0;
            case 2:
                return log(n)+(1);
            case 3:
                if(exp == 0)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return exp*pow(n,exp-1);
            case 4:
                if(exp == 0)
                    return 1.0;
                else
                    return (exp*pow(n,exp-1)*log(n))+(pow(n,exp)*1/n);
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
}

algoritmo initAlgorithem(char *name, typeAlgorithemFunction func, situacion sList[], int ini
        , int mult, int fin, int nTemp){
    algoritmo algoritmo;

    strcpy(algoritmo.alg_name, name);
    algoritmo.func = func;
    algoritmo.ini = ini;
    algoritmo.mult = mult;
    algoritmo.fin = fin;
    algoritmo.nTemp = nTemp;
    memcpy(algoritmo.sList, sList, NUM_SITUACIONES * sizeof(situacion));

    return algoritmo;
}

situacion initSituation(char *name, typeSituationFunction func, cota_t sobre, cota_t ajus, cota_t sub) {
    situacion sit ;
    strcpy(sit.sit_name, name);
    sit.func = func;
    sit.sobre = sobre;
    sit.ajus = ajus;
    sit.sub = sub;
    return sit;
}

void lecturaTiempos_v(algoritmo algoritmos[]){
    int i;
    int j;

    printf(" - Leyendo tiempos \n");
    printf(" ************************************ \n");

    for(i = 0; i<NUM_ALGORITMOS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_SITUACIONES; j++) {
            leerTiempo_v(algoritmos[i],
                         algoritmos[i].sList[j],
                         algoritmos[i].sList[j].tiempos,
                         algoritmos[i].sList[j].valN);
        }
    }
}
void mostrarResultados(algoritmo algoritmos[]){
    int j, i, k;

    int valN;
    double tiempo;

    for(i = 0; i < NUM_ALGORITMOS; i++) {
        for (j = 0;  j < NUM_SITUACIONES; j++) {

            printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\nOrdenación %s con inicialización %s\n\n", algoritmos[i].alg_name
                    , algoritmos[i].sList[j].sit_name);

            printf("   %-10s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-7s\n", "n", "t(n)",algoritmos[i].sList[j].sobre.cota.name,
                   algoritmos[i].sList[j].ajus.cota.name,algoritmos[i].sList[j].sub.cota.name,"anomala");

            for (k = 0; k<algoritmos[i].nTemp; k++) {

                valN = algoritmos[i].sList[j].valN[k];
                tiempo = algoritmos[i].sList[j].tiempos[k].tiempo;

                if(algoritmos[i].sList[j].tiempos[k].is_under_500) {

                    printf("(*)%-10d%-15.5f%-15.8f%-15.8f%-15.8f%7d\n", valN, tiempo,
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].sobre.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].sobre.exp,0),
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].ajus.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].ajus.exp,0),
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].sub.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].sub.exp,0),
                           algoritmos[i].sList[j].tiempos[k].is_anomalo
                    );
                } else {
                    printf("   %-10d%-15.5f%-15.8f%-15.8f%-15.8f%7d\n", valN, tiempo,
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].sobre.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].sobre.exp,0),
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].ajus.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].ajus.exp,0),
                           tiempo / execute(algoritmos[i].sList[j].sub.cota, valN, algoritmos[i].sList[j].sub.exp,0),
                           algoritmos[i].sList[j].tiempos[k].is_anomalo
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y este el algoritmo de ordenacion

```
void insercion (int v[], int n){
    int i;
    int j;
    int aux;

    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        aux = v[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while(j>=0 && v[j]>aux){
            v[j+1] = v[j];
            j--;
        }
        v[j+1] = aux;
    }
}

void fusion(int *v, int Izda, int Dcha, int Ctro){
    int i, j, k;
    int aux[Dcha - Izda + 1];

    i = Izda; j = Ctro + 1; k = Izda;

    while (i <= Ctro && j <= Dcha) aux[k++] = ((v)[i] <= (v)[j]) ? (v)[i++] : (v)[j++];

    while (i <= Ctro) aux[k++] = (v)[i++];

    while (j <= Dcha) aux[k++] = (v)[j++];

    for(k = Izda; k<=Dcha; k++) (v)[k] = aux[k];

}

void fusion_rec(int *v, int Izda, int Dcha){
    int Ctro;
    if(Izda + UMBRAL < Dcha){
        Ctro = (Izda + Dcha) / 2;
        fusion_rec(v, Izda, Ctro);
        fusion_rec(v, Ctro + 1, Dcha);
        fusion(v, Izda, Dcha, Ctro);
    } 
}

void ord_fusion(int *v, int n){
    fusion_rec(v, 0, n - 1);    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    inicializar_semilla();

    //test(10);

    situacion sList[NUM_SITUACIONES] = {
    initSituation("ascendente", ascendente, genCota(Nexp_x, 1.0), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.2), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.4)),
    initSituation("descendente", descendente, genCota(Nexp_x, 1.0), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.2), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.4)),
    initSituation("aleatorio", aleatorio, genCota(Nexp_x, 1.0), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.2), genCota(Nexp_x, 1.4))};

    algoritmo algs[NUM_ALGORITMOS] = {initAlgorithem("fusion", ord_fusion, sList, 500, 2, 30000, 6)};

    lecturaTiempos_v(algs); 

    mostrarResultados(algs);
     /* */
    return 0;
}
```

Para compilar en Ubuntu

```
gcc <file_name>.c -o <binary_name> -lm
```

Para windows creo que no hace falta el -lm

dejo aquí el [enlace git](https://github.com/manucouto1/empiricaLT)

Comment: ¿Estás comprobando si `inicio==0`? Si eso sucede el malloc no va a reservar memoria ya que `sizeof(int)*0 = 0`

Comment: En general el tamaño mínimo del array será de 500 y el tamaño de cada nuevo array crece de forma lineal

Comment: En cualquier caso, en ese código faltan funciones. Por favor, intenta presentar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema

Comment: Si, preferí no poner todo el código porque quedaría un post larguísimo, dejé el enlace al repositorio Git.

Comment: Es que un ejemplo mínimo no debe ser larguísimo... lo que tienes que hacer es coger tu código al completo y eliminar todo lo accesorio, de tal forma que en una cantidad de líneas aceptables tienes un código compilable y ejecutable que reproduce tu problema

Comment: vale, no suelo publicar en Stackoverflow pensé que con el git sería más sencillo, ya he añadido el código necesario para reproducir el error. El ejemplo mínimo para este problema seria una función que reserva memoria dinámica para un vector y llamar a las funciones del algoritmo de ordenación pasando ese vector pero esto no reproduce el error, no se exactamente en que punto esta el problema, de hecho otros algoritmos de ordenación me funcionan sin problemas, me falla con ordenación por fusión, quizás por ser un algoritmo recursivo, heapsort también me dio problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error se produce en la función 'fusion'

```
void fusion(int *v, int Izda, int Dcha, int Ctro){
    int i, j, k;
    int aux[Dcha - Izda + 1];

    i = Izda; j = Ctro + 1; k = Izda;

    while (i <= Ctro && j <= Dcha) aux[k++] = ((v)[i] <= (v)[j]) ? (v)[i++] : (v)[j++];

    while (i <= Ctro) aux[k++] = (v)[i++];

    while (j <= Dcha) aux[k++] = (v)[j++];

    for(k = Izda; k<=Dcha; k++) (v)[k] = aux[k];

}
```

cuando creas el arreglo 'aux', la tendencia es que siempre tiene menos posiciones que el arreglo 'v' (producto de la operación '*Dcha - Izda + 1*'), y en las distintas operaciones sobre el arreglo 'aux', utilizas la variable 'k' que esta inicializada con el valor de 'Izda', me imagino que 'Izda' ira como volante sobre el arreglo principal ('v'), asi como la variable 'Dcha'.

como solución, propongo crear el arreglo 'aux' con el maximo, que me imagino que es el parametro 'Dcha' de la funcion

```
void fusion(int *v, int Izda, int Dcha, int Ctro){
    int i, j, k;
    int aux[Dcha];
```

...

Al menos la aplicación si entrego resultados (fusion.c)

Espero te sirva.